# Can I convert a RAID 0 set to a RAID 5 set?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, hardware, raid

Can I convert a RAID 0 set to a RAID 5 set in a Mac Pro? I currently have two 500GB drives in a RAID 0 set. I want to add a third drive and convert it to  a RAID 5 set. Is it possible to do this without wiping the current array and rebuilding from scratch? If I have to rebuild from scratch, can I take an image of the current state using Carbon Copy Cloner (CCC), kill the RAID 0 set, make the RAID 5 set, and restore from the CCC image?

Answer (score 3):

`Disk Utility` will only support RAID 1 and 0 using software raid.

If you have the [RAID Card for the Mac Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB845Z/A), you can configure RAID 5.  I've never actually used or configured one of these in the wild so I can't give you exact specifics on using it.